# Configuration options for SI 5.0.0, XML or DSL?

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

Am using SI 5.0.0 and a newbie.

WRT to `SI 5.0.0` and `Java8`, what is the configuration option supported as default and moving forward ?

1. XML
2. DSL

Am a bit confused on this new release 5.0.0, as I just started SI from this version. Am not sure, what was the configuration option used in prev releases `(< 5.0.0)`and what is adopted as new configuration option in `5.0.0`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to user preference; there are no plans to deprecate or remove the XML configuration.

Before 5.0, the DSL was also available, but it was in it's own jar with its own version.